# Assigned a ArrayList in AsyncTask, but the change discard afterwords

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I'm writing a simple program to request a JOSN request of a list of earthquakes to display for users. I use Asynctask to put the request in the background thread and use an ArrayList Adaptor to display the relevant information. I declare an empty ArrayList and then extract the JOSN request and put them in a temporary list and then assign the temporary list to the empty ArrayList.

I use a debugger tool to see that in the updateEarthquakeList method. I set the break point in the updateEarthquakeList method. this.earthquak and earthquakes both have 10 elements. Pics are as follow:[image] [image]

But when I set the break point after task.execute(USGS_REQUEST_URL) in the onCreate method, I got this:[image][image]

As the pics shown after execute the AsyncTask the ArrayList is empty. But inside the AsyncTask The array was actually updated. (To do a little experiment I create an int haha as 0 and change it to 1 in the Asynctask, but it changed back to 0 afterwards)

How is this happen and how do I supposted to make it right?

```
 public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = EarthquakeActivity.class.getName();

    ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquak = new ArrayList<Earthquake>();
    int haha = 0;
    private static final String USGS_REQUEST_URL = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&eventtype=earthquake&orderby=time&minmag=6&limit=10";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);

        EarthquakeAsyncTask task = new EarthquakeAsyncTask();
        task.execute(USGS_REQUEST_URL);

        // Create a fake list of earthquake locations.


        // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
        ListView earthquakeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Create a new {@link ArrayAdapter} of earthquakes
        EarthquakeAdapter adapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(this, earthquak);

        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        earthquakeListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //OPEN a web page of a specific when textview is clicked.
        earthquakeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, earthquak.get(position).getUrl());
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateEarthquakeList(ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquake) {
        this.earthquak = earthquake;
        haha = 1;
    }

    private class EarthquakeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Earthquake>> {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Earthquake> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            if (urls.length < 1 || urls[0] == null) {
                return null;
            }
            ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(urls[0]);
            return earthquakes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes) {
            updateEarthquakeList(earthquakes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you know it change back to the old value? where do you put the code to check your arraylist?

Comment: Everything seems ok. You should check again function `QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(urls[0])`.